# Wordpress. Routing. Path variables in permalinks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

[image]

Hi. 
I'm working on a wordpress-app, which is the client app of an API. All client logic (requests & data handling) is done by JS. 
Is there a way to set path variable(s) when creating a new page in Dashboard (**wp-admin->pages->add new**) ? 
For example: 
/club/**first-club** 
/club/**second-club** 
where /club/ is page URL, **first-club** or **second-club** - path variable. But /club/first-club and /club/second-club is the same page. 
It looks like it's not provided by wordpress. There is no information about this anywhere. But I'm still hopeful))). 
Thanks.

Comment: Would it not be cleaner to have all clubs in a custom post type called `club`?

Comment: @joshmoto , what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the feature of the child page

**for example:**
You create a page called "club"
And the next pages you create, you choose "club" as "child page".

More help:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-create-a-child-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This guide describes standart using of child pages. I don't see how to use it in my case.
Doesn't it mean that I'll have to create separate child page for each club?